# Quadratic equation over a global field of characteristic 2

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, global-fields

Let $F=\mathbb F_{2^n}(t)$, and let $f=x^2+ax+b\in F[x]$. Is there any necessary and sufficient condition for $f$, depending on its coefficients, to have a root in $F$? I'm not interested in finding the root, only in knowing whether there is one.

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46505/how-to-solve-a-quadratic-equation-in-characteristic-2, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2108572/quadratic-equation-of-characteristic-2

Answer (score 8):

$b/a^2$ has to be of the form $z^2+z$ for $z\in F$. In order for this to happen, it necessary and sufficient (because $F$ is a rational function field) that $b/a^2$ be of the form $z^2+z$ in every completion of $F$. This you can check by looking at the finitely many places where $b/a^2$ has a pole and verifying that the polar part (including the term with a pole of "order zero") is of the required form. The answer to the question in Daniel's comment goes over the details in the local case.